# Console bar graph using loop, without graphics JAVA

Tags: java, loops, graph, charts

Currently working on example from a book loop chapter. Basically, there are 4 car sellers and each should have input how many cars they sold. Below inputs, their names should be printed out and in same line number of cars they sold(from input), but not in numbers, using X or star *. x or star represents that number input.
Here is my code so far. I am stuck on printing that X or star next to a name. It prints out next to wrong name. Any way using loops only without array?

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class BarGraphCarSold {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter no of cars Bob sold >> ");
    int bobSold = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
    System.out.print("Enter no of cars Pam sold >> ");
    int pamSold = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
    System.out.print("Enter no of cars John sold >> ");
    int johnSold = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
    System.out.print("Enter no of cars Kim sold >> ");
    int kimSold = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Car Sales for Month");


    System.out.print("Bob  \n");
    System.out.print("Pam  \n");
    System.out.print("John  \n");
    System.out.print("Kim  ");

    for(int i = 1; i<=bobSold;i++){
        System.out.print("X");
     }  
   }
 }

OUTPUT
Enter no of cars Bob sold >> 5
Enter no of cars Pam sold >> 7
Enter no of cars John sold >> 4
Enter no of cars Kim sold >> 6

Car Sales for Month
Bob  
Pam  
John  
Kim  XXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

try something like this.

```
System.out.print("Bob ");
for(int i = 0; i < bobSold; i++){
    System.out.print("X");
}
System.out.print("\n");
```

You are printing out each of the names then have  newline (`\n`) then you try to print the X's. So you will need to print their name then the X's then the new line. You will need a loop like that for each of the names you want to print out with their X's.

There are many different ways to do this. You can have a `String` with their name then loop through and add the X's to the `string` then print it all out at one time.

```
String dealer = "Bob ";
for(int i = 0; i < bobSold; i++){
    dealer += "X";
}
dealer += "\n";
System.out.print(dealer);
```

With Arrays

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] dealers = {"Bob","Pam","John","Kim"};
        int[] sales = new int[4];

        try {
            for(int i=0; i < dealers.length; i++){
                System.out.print("Enter number of cars "+dealers[i]+" sold: ");
                sales[i] = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Error Reading input");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Car Sales for Month");

        for(int i = 0; i < dealers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(dealers[i]+" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < sales[i]; j++) {
                if(j == (sales[i]-1)) {
                    System.out.println("X");
                }else {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have fun. Code On.

Comment: Thats right, i was thinking that for each name i would need individual loop.

Comment: System.out.print("Bob  ");
   
   
   for(int i = 1; i<=bobSold;i++){
    
    System.out.print("X");
    
  
  }
   System.out.print("\n");
   System.out.print("Pam  ");
   for(int i = 1; i<=pamSold;i++){
    System.out.print("X");
   }
  
 }  and so on...

Comment: You got it! Each name will need a loop. You just need to look at the sequence of when you print out the info. The name then the X's then the new line. Then repeat until you have printed all the names.

Comment: I tried with String too, it's great solution as well.

Comment: Just wait until you get to `Arrays` then you will really see the power of `for` loops.

Comment: I read array chapter too, and now doing all exercises from the book, i need to code a lot. We went through basic Java on college fast and it was online course, so i really need to get into it. Yes, arrays are powerful and i will do the  same problem with arrays as well.

Comment: Perfect practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the X's for each person.

```
System.out.print("Bob - ");
for(int i = 1; i<=bobSold;i++){
    System.out.print("X");
 }
System.out.print("\nPam - ");
for(int i = 1; i<=pamSold;i++){
    System.out.print("X");
 }
System.out.print("\nSame - ");
for(int i = 1; i<=samSold;i++){
    System.out.print("X");
 }
System.out.print("\nKim - ");
for(int i = 1; i<=kimSold;i++){
    System.out.print("X");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Dodd10x, i tried that and with Strings, both are good simple solutions.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this solution. I personally don't like leading `\n`s that is why I posted what I did. This will still get the job done.

Comment: @NoahHerron - normally I would just use an empty System.out.println().